# Is there a way to fix the port for MockWebServer

Tags: android, mockwebserver

I am trying to use MockWebServer for running my Android test cases.
I am using the server.url("/") to set the path, but I was trying to figure out if there is any way to fix the port as it constantly changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there should be a way, like calling `server.start(port)` but I think the documentation says it all:

[MockWebServer.start(int)](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/mockwebserver/okhttp3/mockwebserver/MockWebServer.html#start-int-)

> Starts the server on the loopback interface for the given port.
>
> Parameters: port - the port to listen to, or 0 for any available port.
>   Automated tests should always use port 0 to avoid flakiness when a
>   specific port is unavailable.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. The reason for me to fix it, so that I can keep a MOCK URL and the retrofit instance could be reused. Is that the correct approach to use since we are running tests serially?

Comment: I have been using a different mock server library in my projects and I don't have any knowledge of MockWebServer so I really cant say.